# Error attempting to reference a deleted function

Tags: c++, vector, reference

I want to initialize `Enemy::copy` using the parameter passed to the initialization constructor, but I get the following error:

```
C2280: 'Enemy &Enemy::operator =(const Enemy &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

Here is the declaration of `class Enemy`:

```
 #include "Pickup.h"
 class Enemy : public Entity
 {
 private:
        std::vector<Pickup>& copy;
 public:
        Enemy::Enemy(std::vector<Pickup>& arraypickup) : copy(arraypickup) {} 
 };
```

And the code from `main()`:

```
std::vector<Pickup> arraypickup;
Enemy enemy(arraypickup);
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: The two lines from `main` that you showed do not cause the error you posted. It is complaining about a deleted copy constructor. None of your code uses copy construction. The error is elsewhere.

Comment: probably `enemy` is passed by value later on

Comment: Later nothing happens with copy, so i don't know whats wrong  ;/

Comment: Melchior, you are referring to the `Enemy::copy`. CoryKramer is referring to the copy constructor function in the Enemy class. You chose a really unfortunate name for that field.

Comment: The problem is most likely your oddly named member `copy`, which is not a copy of anything, but a reference to whatever you pass to the constructor. References are not re-assignable, so the compiler cannot implicitly define a copy assignment operator for your class. So if you try to copy assign something to `Enemy`, you'll see that error.

Comment: Praetorian, you were right, I have replicated the case. May I post an answer based on your idea and my code?

Comment: @iksemyonov Yes, of course. (you should use @<username> so people get notified)

Comment: @Melchior_, has the fix resolved the issue?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is based on the correct suggestion by @Praetorian.

**Short answer with a fix:**

The issue is in the `std::vector<Pickup>& copy;` member of the `Enemy` class. Change that to `std::vector<Pickup> copy;`, removing the reference, to fix the error. Indeed, there is absolutely no need to store the `vector` as a reference, on the contrary, as you can see, having reference members in a class cause errors like the one you've faced. You may have been confused by the fact that the `vector` is passed by reference to the initialization c'tor, but it in no way means that you should also make the class member a reference.

If you still want to store the `Enemy::copy` data by reference, for e.g. performance issues, consider making it a pointer, like so:

```
class Enemy : public Entity
 {
 private:
        std::vector<Pickup>* copy;
 // rest of the class...
 };
```

**Long answer:**

Code to reproduce the issue:

```
class Foo
{
    int& ri;
public:
//    default c'tor can't be defined in a sane fashion  because of the reference member ri
//    Foo() : ri(0) {}
    Foo(int& _ri) : ri(_ri) {}
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i{42};
    Foo f1{i};
    Foo f2{f1}; // we don't have a default constructor so using auto-generated copy c'tor
    f2 = f1; // <--- error
    return 0;
}
```

Results in the error:

```
main.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
main.cpp:14:12: error: use of deleted function 'Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&)'
         f2 = f1; // <--- error
            ^
main.cpp:1:11: note: 'Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&)' is implicitly deleted
                     because the default definition would be ill-formed:
     class Foo
           ^
main.cpp:1:11: error: non-static reference member 'int& Foo::ri',
                      can't use default assignment operator
```

Explanation:

An auto-generated `operator=()`, which would otherwise be generated in this case [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4944131/342384)], is considered to be `ill-formed` due to the fact the you can't  reassign references in C++ [[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293674/can-we-reassign-the-reference-in-c)]. The auto-generated `operator=(Foo& other)`, should it exist, would attempt to perform `this->ri = other.ri`, which is considered to be incorrect ("ill-formed", as reported by the compiler), since it's a re-assignment of the reference `ri`.

Finally, I suggest to see [[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120228/assignment-operator-and-copy-constructor-in-the-presence-of-references)], with an in-depth answer on the issue.

1. [about auto-generated copy assignment operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4944131/342384)
2. [about re-assigning references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293674/can-we-reassign-the-reference-in-c)
3. [Assignment operator and copy constructor in the presence of references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6120228/assignment-operator-and-copy-constructor-in-the-presence-of-references)